# Loading calendar web part while hidden causing events to render incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, sharepoint-2013

I have multiple calendar web parts on a page, and I am using the [tabbed web part zone](http://sharepointtabs.codeplex.com/) to put each calendar in a tab.

The problem is that the calendar web part renders, and then uses AJAX to get the calendar events. Once the data comes back from the server, it creates DOM elements that are `position:absolute` to place them on the calendar.

The calendar in the first tab is fine (since it's visible), but the others are having problems. The events are all in the upper-left corner of the calendar (presumably because the position of the events couldn't be correctly calculated since the DOM element is hidden).

The closest I've come to solving this problem is to use the following javascript:

```
SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarInstanceRepository.lookupInstance(instanceId).refreshItems();
```

There are two problems with this: 1) This is an ajax call, so there is some delay and the user sees the events "snap" into place on the calendar and 2) the layout of the calendar itself looks weird, because for some reason, the weeks that have events in them are rendered as being less than half the height of the other weeks on the calendar.

I've also tried not hiding the calendars during the initial loading process (moving them off screen), and I am getting the same problem, but even if that works, I still have a problem with the calendars that are hidden if the user resizes the browser.

What I really need is for there to be a method on the CalendarInstance that would redraw/recalculate everything, but do it client-side only.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well, were you able to find anything to fix this?

Comment: I did just a couple of days ago. I forgot to come back here and post the answer. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, I found a work around.

Basically, instead of showing/hiding tabs, I treated it more like a carousel (or a slider). I essentially allow all of my tabs be visible and wrap them with a container. I set the height of the container and hide the overflow, so you can only actually see one at a time. This is a less extreme idea from what I described in my question. I can't speak to why that didn't work, but this solution did, but the idea is essentially the same: don't hide the calendars in the DOM, simply make only one of them them visible to the user; doing it that way allows the SP JavaScript to make the proper calculation for the event items.

I wrote up a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2LAs/2/) that shows a simplistic version of what I did (my code is a little more complicated). Here's the basic DOM structure:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li data-tabid="tab1">Tab One</li>
        <li data-tabid="tab2">Tab Two</li>
        <li data-tabid="tab3">Tab Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="tab1">Tab 1</div>
            <div id="tab2">Tab 2</div>
            <div id="tab3">Tab 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```